# Akka websocket - how to close connection by server?

Tags: scala, akka, akka-http

So here is my websocket server implementation.

```scala
val route = get {
  pathEndOrSingleSlash {
    handleWebSocketMessages(websocketFlow)
  }
}

def websocketFlow: Flow[Message, Message, Any] =
  Flow[Message]
    .collect { case TextMessage.Strict(textMessage) => protocol.hydrate(textMessage) }
    .via(chatActorFlow(UUID.randomUUID()))
    .map(event => TextMessage.Strict(protocol.serialize(event)))


def chatActorFlow(connectionId: UUID) : Flow[Protocol.Message, Protocol.Event, Any] = {

  val sink = Flow[Protocol.Message]
    .map(msg => Protocol.SignedMessage(connectionId, msg))
    .to(Sink.actorRef(chatRef, Protocol.CloseConnection(connectionId)))

  val source = Source
      .mapMaterializedValue {
        actor : ActorRef => {
          chatRef ! Protocol.OpenConnection(actor, connectionId)
        }
      }

  Flow.fromSinkAndSource(sink, source)
}
```

I'm wondering if there is any way to close connection once message of type `ConnectionClosed` is sent by `chatRef`?

Comment: From the code, it looks like `chatRef` will actually *receive* a `ConnectionClosed` message (as an onComplete message for the `Sink.actorRef`). Could you clarify what you want to achieve?

Comment: I would like manually close the connection from the server side. Lets assume that I have a list of "banned users", each time when banned user opens a connection I would like to close it by server.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The solution below allows to drop connections from the server side by terminating the Actor materialized by the `Source.actorRef` stage. This is simply done by sending a `PoisonPill` to it.

Now, it is still not clear to me how you'd like to identify a "banned" client at connection time, so the example is - on purpose - very simple: the server drops any connection after a maximum amount of clients are connected. If you want to use any other strategy to kick out clients at any time, you can still apply the same logic and send `PoisonPill` to their own source actors.

```
object ChatApp extends App {

  implicit val system = ActorSystem("chat")
  implicit val executor: ExecutionContextExecutor = system.dispatcher
  implicit val materializer = ActorMaterializer()

  val route = get {
    pathEndOrSingleSlash {
      handleWebSocketMessages(websocketFlow)
    }
  }

  val maximumClients = 1

  class ChatRef extends Actor {
    override def receive: Receive = withClients(Map.empty[UUID, ActorRef])

    def withClients(clients: Map[UUID, ActorRef]): Receive = {
      case SignedMessage(uuid, msg) => clients.collect{
        case (id, ar) if id == uuid => ar ! msg
      }
      case OpenConnection(ar, uuid) if clients.size == maximumClients => ar ! PoisonPill
      case OpenConnection(ar, uuid) => context.become(withClients(clients.updated(uuid, ar)))
      case CloseConnection(uuid) => context.become(withClients(clients - uuid))
    }
  }

  object Protocol {
    case class SignedMessage(uuid: UUID, msg: String)
    case class OpenConnection(actor: ActorRef, uuid: UUID)
    case class CloseConnection(uuid: UUID)
  }

  val chatRef = system.actorOf(Props[ChatRef])

  def websocketFlow: Flow[Message, Message, Any] =
    Flow[Message]
      .mapAsync(1) {
        case TextMessage.Strict(s) => Future.successful(s)
        case TextMessage.Streamed(s) => s.runFold("")(_ + _)
        case b: BinaryMessage => throw new Exception("Binary message cannot be handled")
      }.via(chatActorFlow(UUID.randomUUID()))
      .map(TextMessage(_))

  def chatActorFlow(connectionId: UUID) : Flow[String, String, Any] = {

    val sink = Flow[String]
      .map(msg => Protocol.SignedMessage(connectionId, msg))
      .to(Sink.actorRef(chatRef, Protocol.CloseConnection(connectionId)))

    val source = Source.actorRef(16, OverflowStrategy.fail)
      .mapMaterializedValue {
        actor : ActorRef => {
          chatRef ! Protocol.OpenConnection(actor, connectionId)
        }
      }

    Flow.fromSinkAndSource(sink, source)
  }

  Http().bindAndHandle(route, "0.0.0.0", 8080)
    .map(_ => println(s"Started server..."))

}
```

Comment: hey, this is the answer I was looking for! In my case clients has to authenticate themselves in 30 seconds after connection is open, in other case server should drop the connection. `PoisonPill` does the job excellent, thanks!

Comment: `case (id, ar) if id != uuid => ar ! msg` should be change to `case (id, ar) if id == uuid => ar ! msg` then the websocket will receive the message it send..