# Akka. How to close a websocket connection from server?

Tags: kotlin, akka, akka-stream, akka-http

I am learning the akka framework and i am trying to close a websocket connection from server.

```
fun main() {

    val system = ActorSystem.create("system")
    val materializer = Materializer.createMaterializer(system)

    val http = Http.get(system)

    val routeFlow = path("ws") {
        get {
            parameter("as") { sys ->
                parameter("id") { id ->
                    parameter("v") { v ->
                        handleWebSocketMessages(mainFlow(sys, id, v))
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }.flow(system, materializer)

    http.newServerAt("0.0.0.0", 8080).withMaterializer(materializer).bindFlow(routeFlow).thenRun {
        println("Web socket server is running at localhost:8080")
    }
}

fun mainFlow(sys: String, id: String, v: String): Flow<Message, Message, NotUsed> {
    val source = Source.actorRef<Message>(
        { Optional.empty() },
        { Optional.empty() },
        100,
        OverflowStrategy.fail())
        .mapMaterializedValue {
            it.tell(PoisonPill.getInstance(), ActorRef.noSender())
        }

    val sink = Flow.create<Message>()
        .map {
            
        }
        .to(Sink.onComplete {
            
        })

    return Flow.fromSinkAndSource(sink, source)
}
```

I am doing it here:

```
.mapMaterializedValue {
    it.tell(PoisonPill.getInstance(), ActorRef.noSender())
}
```

I checked this [Akka websocket - how to close connection by server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41316173/akka-websocket-how-to-close-connection-by-server?rq=1). But it is not working. I am getting an error:

```
PoisonPill message sent to StageActor(akka://system/system/Materializers/StreamSupervisor-1/$$c-actorRefSource) will be ignored, since it is not a real Actor.Use a custom message type to communicate with it instead.
```

What am i doing wrong and how to close it?

Solution:

```
fun mainFlow(connectionsController: ActorRef, sys: String, id: String, v: String, system: ActorSystem): Flow<Message, Message, NotUsed> {
    val source = Source.actorRef<Message>(
        {
            if (it is Done) {
                Optional.of(CompletionStrategy.immediately())
            } else {
                Optional.empty()
            }
        },
        { Optional.empty() },
        16,
        OverflowStrategy.fail())
        .mapMaterializedValue {
            it.tell(Done.done(), ActorRef.noSender())
        }

    val sink = Flow.create<Message>()
        .map {
            
        }
        .to(Sink.onComplete {
            
        })

    return Flow.fromSinkAndSource(sink, source)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The server will close the connection when its upstream completes.

The previous answer relied on an older version's behavior around `PoisonPill`, which would trigger completion.

With a `Source.actorRef`, the first function argument is the completion matcher: send a message for which that  function returns a non-empty `Optional` and the source will complete.  The content of that `Optional` is the completion strategy, which governs whether the source completes the stream immediately or whether it will drain its buffer.

I'm not that familiar with Kotlin, so I can't provide any code, but I think the `mapMaterializedValue` is not where you want to close the connection, as that code will execute before the source has a chance to send any messages across the websocket.

Comment: Could you provide scala code? It will be easier to understand

Comment: Resolved. Thanks a lot. I will modify my question for other users.

Comment: And one more question. Is there a way to close it with code?
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CloseEvent

Comment: This inspired example: https://github.com/pbernet/akka_streams_tutorial/blob/master/src/main/scala/akkahttp/WebsocketEchoActors.scala shows the closing on server side upon explicit closing the ws connection on the browser client. Maybe it helps

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69655125/use-a-actor-as-a-source-to-my-websocket-client-flow... broadly what you will need to do is propagate the materialized value of the `Source.actorRef` through to be part of the materialized value of the stream (using `preMaterialize` (probably inside a `Source.fromMaterializer`) to inject the materialized `ActorRef` into the stream might also work in some cases) and then send that `ActorRef` a `Done` when you want to close the socket.  You will almost certainly not want to `mapMaterializedValue`, as that will happen too early.