# Use a Actor as a source to my Websocket client flow

Tags: scala, akka-stream

I currently have a simple TextMessage Source that sends messages to my Websocket client flow like this:

```
     val incoming: Sink[Message, Future[Done]] =
      Sink.foreach[Message] {
        case message: TextMessage.Strict =>
          println(message.text)
        case _ =>
      }

    // send this as a message over the WebSocket
    val outgoing: Source[TextMessage.Strict, NotUsed] = Source
      .combine(
        Source.single(
          TextMessage(
            """{"auth":"APIKEY-123"}"""
          )
        ),
        Source.single(
          TextMessage(
            """{"topic":"topic123"}"""
          )
        ),
        Source.never
      )(Merge(_))
      .throttle(1, 1.second)

    val webSocketFlow = Http().webSocketClientFlow(
      WebSocketRequest("wss://socket.polygon.io/stocks")
    )

    val (upgradeResponse, closed) =
      outgoing
        .viaMat(webSocketFlow)(
          Keep.right
        ) // keep the materialized Future[WebSocketUpgradeResponse]
        .toMat(incoming)(Keep.both) // also keep the Future[Done]
        .run()

    val connected = upgradeResponse.flatMap { upgrade =>
      if (upgrade.response.status == StatusCodes.SwitchingProtocols) {
        Future.successful(Done)
      } else {
        throw new RuntimeException(
          s"Connection failed: ${upgrade.response.status}"
        )
      }
    }
```

So I currently have a Source of type Source[TextMessage.Strict, NotUsed], but I want to use the commented out code where I have a ActorRef as my source.

I tried this:

```
  val actorSource: Source[Any, ActorRef] = Source.actorRef(
  completionMatcher = { case Done =>
    CompletionStrategy.immediately
  },
  failureMatcher = PartialFunction.empty,
  bufferSize = 100,
  overflowStrategy = OverflowStrategy.dropHead
)

val actorRef: ActorRef = actorSource.to(Sink.foreach(println)).run()
actorRef !  """{"auth":"APIKEY-123"}"""

val webSocketFlow = Http().webSocketClientFlow(
  WebSocketRequest("wss://socket.polygon.io/stocks")
)

val (upgradeResponse, closed) =
  actorSource
    .viaMat(webSocketFlow)(
      Keep.right
    ) // keep the materialized Future[WebSocketUpgradeResponse]
    .toMat(incoming)(Keep.both) // also keep the Future[Done]
    .run()
```

So when I am using a ActorRef as my source, I am having a hard time trying to fit this into the graph.   I am getting this compile time error:

> type mismatch; [error]  found   :
> akka.stream.scaladsl.Flow[akka.http.scaladsl.model.ws.Message,akka.http.scaladsl.model.ws.Message,scala.concurrent.Future[akka.http.scaladsl.model.ws.WebSocketUpgradeResponse]]
> [error]  required:
> akka.stream.Graph[akka.stream.FlowShape[String,?],?] [error]
> .viaMat(webSocketFlow)(

**Note**:  I want a Actor as my source, and also as my sink i.e. pass all messages that result from the flow to another actor as a sink.

Can someone explain what am I currently doing wrong with my Actor as a source and trying to add it to my flow/graph?

**Update**

Here is the code I have now:

```
def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    implicit val system = ActorSystem()
    import system.dispatcher

    val incoming: Sink[Message, Future[Done]] =
      Sink.foreach[Message] {
        case message: TextMessage.Strict =>
          println(message.text)
        case _ =>
        // ignore other message types
      }

    val actorSource = Source.actorRef[String](
      completionMatcher = { case Done =>
        CompletionStrategy.immediately
      },
      failureMatcher = PartialFunction.empty,
      bufferSize = 100,
      overflowStrategy = OverflowStrategy.dropHead
    )

    val webSocketFlow = Http().webSocketClientFlow(
      WebSocketRequest("wss://socket.polygon.io/stocks")
    )

    // the materialized value is a tuple with
    // upgradeResponse is a Future[WebSocketUpgradeResponse] that
    // completes or fails when the connection succeeds or fails
    // and closed is a Future[Done] with the stream completion from the incoming sink
    val ((sendActor, upgradeResponse), closed) =
      actorSource
        .viaMat(webSocketFlow)(
          Keep.both
        ) // keep the materialized Future[WebSocketUpgradeResponse]
        .toMat(incoming)(Keep.both) // also keep the Future[Done]
        .run()

    // just like a regular http request we can access response status which is available via upgrade.response.status
    // status code 101 (Switching Protocols) indicates that server support WebSockets
    val connected = upgradeResponse.flatMap { upgrade =>
      if (upgrade.response.status == StatusCodes.SwitchingProtocols) {
        Future.successful(Done)
      } else {
        throw new RuntimeException(
          s"Connection failed: ${upgrade.response.status}"
        )
      }
    }

    sendActor ! TextMessage("""{"auth":"APIKEY-123"}""")
    sendActor ! TextMessage("""{"topic":"topic123"}""")

    //in a real application you would not side effect here
    connected.onComplete(println)
    closed.foreach(_ => println("closed"))
  }
```

I am getting the following compile errors:

> [error] The argument types of an anonymous function must be fully
> known. (SLS 8.5) [error] Expected type was: ? [error]
> completionMatcher = { case Done => [error]                           ^
> [error] /home/blank/scala/testing/streamsapp/ws2.scala:57:37: value
> flatMap is not a member of Any [error]     val connected =
> upgradeResponse.flatMap { upgrade => [error]
> ^ [error] /home/blank/scala/testing/streamsapp/ws2.scala:67:15: value
> ! is not a member of Any [error]     sendActor !
> TextMessage("""{"auth":"APIKEY-123"}""") [error]               ^
> [error] /home/blank/scala/testing/streamsapp/ws2.scala:68:15: value !
> is not a member of Any [error]     sendActor !
> TextMessage("""{"topic":"topic123"}""") [error]               ^
> [error] /home/blank/scala/testing/streamsapp/ws2.scala:72:12: value
> foreach is not a member of Any [error]     closed.foreach(_ =>
> println("closed")) [error]            ^ [error] 5 errors found

Comment: Remember that `actorSource` is a `Source` so you won't get an `ActorRef` until you `run` it, and you get a different `ActorRef` each time. And probably worth using `Message` rather than `Any` in the `source.ActorRef` declaration

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your compiler error is arising from your `actorSource` not outputting `Message` but `String` (that error shouldn't be the one you'd get with your code, perhaps you tried changing it to a `Source[String, ActorRef]`?): since the `webSocketFlow` only processes `Message`s, it can only be attached to a source of `Message`.

So I suggest something along the lines of:

```scala
val immediateCompletion: PartialFunction[Any, CompletionStrategy] = {
  case Done => CompletionStrategy.immediately
}

val actorSource = Source.actorRef[Message](
  completionMatcher = immediateCompletion,
  failureMatcher = PartialFunction.empty,
  bufferSize = 100,
  overflowStrategy = OverflowStrategy.dropHead
)

val webSocketFlow = Http().webSocketClientFlow(
  WebSocketRequest("wss://socket.polygon.io/stocks")
)

val ((sendActor, upgradeResponse), closed) =
  actorSource
    .viaMat(webSocketFlow)(Keep.both)  // keep both the actor and the upgradeResponse
    .toMat(incoming)(Keep.both)  // ...and also keep the closed
    .run()

sendActor ! TextMessage("""{"auth":"APIKEY-123"}""")
sendActor ! TextMessage("""{"topic":"topic123"}""")
```

Comment: I updated my question with my code and errors, still getting compile errors related to the upgradeesponse and also the `any` issue...

Comment: See edit... idk why I wrote `Source.actorRef[String]`

Comment: What's the best way to fully understand the different types that are required by all these connectors like `viaMat` and `toMat` etc?   I am missing something b/c I feel lost! :)

Comment: I updated the actorRef type to a Message, but I am still getting those same compilation errors...hmm.

Comment: You're using Akka 2.6, right?  The API for `Source.actorRef` slightly changed from 2.5 to 2.6.  The type inference seems to be messed up for the `completionMatcher`, so see edit

Comment: `viaMat` and `toMat` allow you to manipulate the "materialized value" of the stream, which is a sort of side-channel that allows the stream to interact while it's running with the surrounding program (e.g. reporting status as in `upgradeResponse` and `closed` or allowing values to be injected into the stream as in `sendActor`).  `via` and `to` are each equivalent to their `Mat` counterparts with `Keep.left` (which means discarding the materialized value of the stages you're going via or to).

Comment: ` [ERROR] [akka.actor.ActorSystemImpl] [] [default-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-6] - Websocket handler failed with class java.lang.String cannot be cast to class akka.http.scaladsl.model.ws.Message (java.lang.String is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap'; akka.http.scaladsl.model.ws.Message is in unnamed module of loader sbt.internal.LayeredClassLoader @1eedfd89) MDC: {akkaAddress=akka://default, sourceThread=default-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-8, akkaSource=akka.actor.ActorSystemImpl(default), sourceActorSystem=default, akkaTimestampe`

Comment: Yes I am using 2.6.8

Comment: what messages are you sending to the `sendActor`?

Comment: I was sending it just plain text, I wrapped it in a `TextMessage` and it worked, very much appreciate your help!